# Not able to update table using tkinter in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, updates, pymysql

I'm unable to update my table in MySQL using Tkinter. It just won't get updated. I have tried checking where the table name is different but it's not. It shows no errors but not getting updated.

```py
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()
t.geometry("500x500")
Label(text = 'Name:').place(x=10,y=10)
nm = Entry()
nm.place(x=55,y=12)

Label(text = 'age:').place(x=10,y=35)
ag = Entry()
ag.place(x=55,y=37)


def abcd():
        import pymysql
        x = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'root',password = 'admin',db ='db')
        cur = x.cursor()
        n= nm.get()
        a = ag.get()
        cur.execute('insert into sample2 values(%s, %s)',(n,a))
        x.commit()
        x.close()
        
   


Button(text ='Submit',command = abcd).place(x=40,y=65)

Label(text ='UPDATE',fg = 'white',bg = 'black',font = ('Times new roman',24,'bold')).place(x=10,y=100)
Label(text ='Enter the name to update').place(x = 5,y = 155)
b=Entry()
b.place(x = 150, y = 157)
Label(text = 'Enter new age:').place(x=5,y = 200)
nag = Entry()
nag.place(x=150,y = 202)
'''print(b)'''

def upd():
        import pymysql
        x = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'root',password = 'admin',db ='db')
        cur = x.cursor()
        gnd =b.get()
        anag = nag.get()
        cur.execute('update sample2 set age =%s  where name = %s',(gnd,anag))
        x.commit()
        x.close()
        t.mainloop()



Button(text = 'apply',command = upd).place(x = 200, y = 300)
                
t.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the order of the arguments used in UPDATE is wrong:

```py
cur.execute('update sample2 set age =%s  where name = %s',(gnd,anag)) # wrong order of arguments
```

So the WHERE clause is evaluated as False and no record will be updated.

It should be:

```py
cur.execute('update sample2 set age =%s  where name = %s',(anag, gnd))
```